# MATLAB Engine in Qt C++ Specified Module Could Not be Found

Tags: c++, matlab, qt-creator

Using MATLAB 2018a or newer, integrating with Qt 5.15.2.  Tried the instructions here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/build-c-engine-programs.html

So my .pro file looks as follows:

```
# MATLAB Engine Includes
LIBS += -LC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64 -llibMatlabEngine
LIBS += -LC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64 -llibMatlabDataArray
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include
DEPENDPATH += C:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include
```

Then some of my code looks as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<matlab::engine::MATLABEngine> matlabPtr;

// Instantiate interface to MATLAB
std::vector<std::u16string> matlabInstances;
matlabInstances = matlab::engine::findMATLAB(); // find any existing MATLAB instances

if (!matlabInstances.empty()) { // if we have one, connect to it
    matlabPtr = matlab::engine::connectMATLAB(matlabInstances[0]);
} else { // if we don't have one, create a new one*/
    matlabPtr = matlab::engine::startMATLAB();
}
```

When I go to run this, I get an error message in Qt Application Output that says:

```
The specified module could not be found.
```

I commented out individual lines and found that even if I comment out the call to findMATLAB(), the same error occurs at the first call using the matlab::engine namespace.

I thought this was maybe a similar issue to Qt where you have to either statically link the libraries or copy the dlls into the local run folder, so I copied the dll files from the C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\bin\win64 into the debug folder and had no additional luck.

Is this a dependency issue?  How do I figure out which module is unfindable?  Does anyone have a more complete list of steps required to get MATLAB integrated with 2018a MATLAB or later?  I found many results for older versions of MATLAB, but they had different header files and folder structures that don't seem to match.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution...if I add the MATLAB path to C:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\bin\win64 to my PATH variable, it works as expected, so I just need to organize the .dll files to be on the PATH.  Would be interested in information on why I couldn't copy the dlls to my local directory to make them work.